# ejs.filters is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to understand ejs filters, but I can't get it working:

Server.js

```
var ejs  = require('ejs');

ejs.filters.test = function() {

//empty for test

};
```

Routes.js

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index.ejs', {
        data : someData
    });

});
```

Index.ejs:

```
<% test %>
```

Error:

```
...test is not defined 
at buf.push.__stack.lineno (eval at <anonymous> ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter is applied to some data with the following syntax.

```
<%=: data | test %>
```

Where you are missing the `=:` and the data to be filtered.